# Avoid retrofit POJO redundancy

Tags: android, retrofit2, pojo

I have a POJO class for retrofit.

```
    public class AppData(){
      String a;
      String b;
      String c;
      String d;

      public void  setA(String a){
          this.a = a;
       }
      public String getA(){
         return a;
       }
      public void setB(String b){
          this.b = b;
       }
      public String getB(){
         return b;
       }
      public void setC(String c){
          this.c = c;
       }
      public String getC(){
         return c;
       }
      public void setD(String d){
          this.d = d;
       }
      public String getD(){
         return d;
       }
  }
```

I have 3 different retrofit request where I need AppData class. But in request 1, I need only attributes a and b. In request 2, I need only a,b,c  and in the third request I need only b,c and d.
On reference I found solutions like adding transient keyword,adding annotations etc. But I didn't get a solution. Is there any way to use the same POJO class for all these 3 requests ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use the same POJO class without getting any error. The rest of the variables will be null

Comment: What error are you getting in it, as it will work perfectly just put the unused fields value null while doing serialize and deserialize?

Comment: Initially when I tried there were some issues with that implementation and to manage time I made it redundant. Now I have already reached the project in depth and need to know if I remove redundancy that will cause problem or not. thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing right, only one class is enough, in Call pass your AppData class for all three request.

```
Call<AppData>
```

Whatever value is returned in response will be updated for example for first request only a, b will be set similarly for other request respective variables will be set, so while retrieving you can use respective **getters**

So for fist request do not try to retrieve c and d, or else you will get **NullPointer** only use

```
response.getA();
response.getB();
```

**Similarly for other request use those which are returned in response**

Comment: if you try to run `getC()` or `getD()` and it wasn't deserialized you won't get a `NullPointer` exception you will just get `null` back. This might be useful if you are checking if the value came back or not.

Comment: @carlpoole is right value null will be returned, if you try to use those variable for condition checking, etc, then you will be getting NullPointer

Answer (score 2):

The `AppData` object will work for all 3 requests. The values that aren't deserialized from a server response will just be `null`.